# html5 videos giving 404 errors

Tags: html, .htaccess, video

I'm trying to do a background video for a banner. When I view the page locally everything works just fine, but when I load it on a server the video won't load. I do get the fallback jpeg properly displayed but for all three video files the console shows a 404 error.

```
<video autoplay loop class="fillWidth" poster="img/Push-The-Buttons.jpg">
            <source src="img/Push-the-Buttons.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
            <source src="img/Push-the-Buttons.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>
            <source src="img/Push-the-Buttons.webm" type="video/webm"/>
            Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.
        </video>
```

I've triple checked all of the paths but I'm finding nothing. I've tried putting an .htaccess file in the home folder and the folder with the media, and here's what I put in it:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
AddType video/mp4 .mov
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType image/jpeg .jpeg .jpg .jpe .JPG
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: filenames are case sensitive in linux. make sure you have the EXACT filename on your server.

Comment: Yeah, turns out all of the "-the-" should have had uppercase t's. Looks like I did a lot of work to try to debug something simple. Thanks though!

Comment: please accept my answer as the correct solution

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to right-click on my project in Eclipse, and correct the invalid entries in the Java Build Path.

Answer (score -1):

Check if your file names are correct. File names are case sensitive on Linux but not on windows